# If two Riemann integrable functions are equal except at one point, then the integrals are equal

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f(x)$ an $g(x)$ be integrable functions over $[a,b]$ and let $\alpha$ be a point of $[a,b]$ if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x\neq \alpha$, then $$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx=\int_{[a,b]}g(x)dx.$$

So is it okay to say, since $f(x)=g(x)\Rightarrow f(x)-g(x)=0$. Then also given that both functions are integrable I can say that for $f(x)$ to be Riemann integral there is a $|T-K|<\varepsilon$ if $\max(x_i-x_{i-1})<\delta$. For $g(x)$ to be Riemann integral there is a $|T-K|<\varepsilon$ if $\max(x_i-x_{i-1})<\delta$ and then set them equal to each other?

I'm really confused where my next step is, and finding delta is becoming a little abstract. Please can someone help me solve or give me a nice push in the right direction?

Comment: Presumably you are using the Riemann definition of the integral. When you make a partition of $[a,b]$, consider the subinterval which contains $\alpha$ separately to the rest of the partition.

Comment: Try breaking things into 3 integrals.  The first from $a$ to $\alpha - \epsilon$.  The second from $\alpha - \epsilon$ to $\alpha + \epsilon$.  Then the third from $\alpha + \epsilon$ to $a$.  Try to bound each of these integrals individually and then send $\epsilon$ to zero.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As [cnick suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339575/proof-if-fx-gx-then-int-fx-int-gx#comment2722599_1339575): split both integrals as 
$$
\int_a^b = \int_a^{\alpha-\epsilon}+\int_{\alpha-\epsilon}^{\alpha+\epsilon} + \int_{\alpha+\epsilon}^b \tag{1}
$$
The goal is to show that 
$$\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx - \int_{[a,b]}g(x)dx = 0 \tag{2}$$
With the split as in $(1)$, the difference of integrals becomes
$$\int_{\alpha-\epsilon}^{\alpha+\epsilon}f(x)dx - \int_{\alpha-\epsilon}^{\alpha+\epsilon}g(x)dx = \int_{\alpha-\epsilon}^{\alpha+\epsilon}(f(x)-g(x))dx \tag{3}$$
This can be estimated: for example, let $M=\max(\sup|f-g|)$; then the right hand side of $(3)$ is at most $2M\epsilon$. Thus, 
$$\left|\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx - \int_{[a,b]}g(x)dx\right|\le 2M\epsilon$$
and since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, the difference is actually $0$.