# Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> If $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \not= c$, where $a < c < b$. Show that $f$ is
> Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and
> $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx = 0$.

I have a little confusion about this problem. I considered two cases $f(c)>0$ and $f(c)<0$ with partition $P_n$ as $P_n= \{a,x_1,x_2,...,b\} $ where $x_k=a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}$ and assuming c $ \in [x_{k-1},x_{k} ]$ then I proved $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx = 0$ but my teacher considered two cases where c is inside the interval $ [x_{k-1},x_{k} ]$ and c is the one of the end point of $ [x_{k-1},x_{k} ]$.

Is that necessary?

Comment: Are we assuming that $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere?

Comment: @Alphyte yes of course

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2888823/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857961/42969  or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339575/42969.

Comment: @MartinR can you please tell me is that  necessary to consider c inside the interval and end point ?

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: @MartinR thank you very much